# Unmanaged Ethernet switch silicon?

Tags: ethernet

I need to add an unmanaged Ethernet switch circuit to my PCB, but I can't find any usable silicon, not even with 100BaseT. Am I missing something? I don't want to have to connect it to a microprocessor. I need available datasheet/reference design/parts so that rules out Broadcom and Intel silicon which seems geared toward OEMs.

Note this it not a "pick the best part" for me question, but rather a "help me solve this electronic design problem that appears to have no solution" question. If the best way is to implement it without using a dedicated Ethernet switch IC, that is a solution too.

Comment: Huh, I can't seem to find any useful silicon either.

Comment: I think this is off-topic

Comment: Someone want to explain why I am getting minus points for this question? The answer is not already in EE Stack Exchange and it is definitely an electrical engineering related question.

Comment: It's a good question, however, this site is not intended for component recommendations or questions whos answers may quickly become outdated (e.g. when a better part is put on the market).

Comment: Regardless whether you say if it is not a pick the best part kind of question or not, thats exactly what it is.  This is off-topic

Comment: This is off topic and it's going to be closed by those that do such things-- and very soon. Try looking for Taiwan-based suppliers.

Comment: "Am I missing something" is not a "SPECIFIC product or place" question.  You don't like the question? Perhaps a new policy would be in order, because using the "SPECIFIC product" policy to block this one is not sensible.

Comment: This is being blocked because while OP isn't asking for a specific product, the only useful answers are those that list specific products.

Comment: Shannon- If you are correct, and if there are no ICs or modules that perform this function available to non-oems (which I now believe is the case), than that is my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Former SMSC products: [Ethernet Switches](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/technology/ethernet/devices/products/switches.html).

Maybe you can use these.

Comment: Thanks, but these are managed ICs.

Comment: Unmanaged and managed switches use the same ICs. The difference is just whether the user has access to the management interface.

Answer (score 2):

Would an embedded switch module work in your application, rather than an ASIC?

Sixnet makes a 6 port managed switch on a small PCB that you can integrate into your system.
[ET-5MS-OEM Industrial Ethernet Switch](http://www.sixnet.com/product/et5msoem-industrial-ethernet-switch-115.cfm)
(I know you're looking for a basic unmanaged solution - but perhaps the default or some other hard coded configuration will work for you and you wont need to worry about it).

EDIT: They make an 8 port gigabit version too now: [ET-8MG-OEM Industrial Ethernet Switch](http://www.sixnet.com/product/et8mgoem-industrial-ethernet-switch-242.cfm).

I have gotten some of Broadcomm's data sheets before. Technically I was working as an OEM but my yields were low - 10-20PCBs (custom contract design work). I had to sign an NDA and we had to blow some smoke about working for a fortune 500 company etc to get them to cooperate though. Is this for any commercial application, or hobby work? Perhaps you can get an application engineer to help you out if you pitch what you're trying to do to them.

EDIT: If you end up going the route of adding a UC, you could use several WIZNET chips (e.g. [W5500](http://www.wiznet.co.kr/sub_modules/en/product/Product_Detail.asp?cate1=5&cate2=7&cate3=77&pid=1193)) in [MACRAW mode](http://www.wiznet.co.kr/Admin_Root/UpLoad_Files/EditorFiles/How_to_implement_MACRAW_for_W7100_v1_1_en.pdf). 
Your MCU would need to poll each of the devices, maintain a list of the MAC address associated with the device at each port, and direct the data accordingly.

Or perhaps put a cluster of [these guys (W7100A)](http://www.wiznet.co.kr/sub_modules/en/product/Product_Detail.asp?cate1=5&cate2=7&cate3=86&pid=1131) on the same bus.